# Facebook native share dialog feature "is not available presently" on iOS

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to integrate SDK 3.5 into my iOS app. I can make the facebook app to pop up the share dialog and ask me to input text. But once I tap "Post" it shows me an alert "Beta Feature This feature is not available presently". Is this a temporary error or something I need to turn on in my app settings? Here is a screenshot of the error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yu8fgh46prmp1aw/Photo%20Apr%2025%2C%2010%2046%2002%20PM.png

Answer (score 1):

This feature is enabled only in Beta as of now. You need to add this line to your share dialog code to make this work.

// Set this flag on to enable the Share Dialog beta feature
    [FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesShareDialog];

For more details, you can see the how-to here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/

Comment: I am already calling the enableBetaFeature function. The error is happening inside facebook app. I added a screenshot to the question. BTW, facebook app often crashes before showing me the share dialog, or after I tap the "cancel" button instead of "post".

Comment: Ahh I see. Did you add FacebookDisplayName parameter in your project info and .plist file? That's the reason for the crash when you press on post.

Comment: Yes, I have FacebookDisplayName which matches app settings. Pressing "post" only gives me the error dialog. Crash occurs when I press "cancel", or sometimes before the post dialog appears.

Comment: Interesting. I assume you have the latest Facebook Native app for iOS installed(6.0+)?

Comment: Yes, I already tried deleting and re-installing the facebook app. Same results. I am testing on iPhone 4 running iOS 6.1.3.